# I need all value from JSON array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table in which I have JSON data and the field type is NVARCHAR(4000)

```
    [
        {"number":1,"booked":0},
        {"number":2,"booked":0},
        {"number":3,"booked":0},
        {"number":4,"booked":1},
        {"number":5,"booked":0},
        {"number":6,"booked":0},
        {"number":7,"booked":0},
        {"number":8,"booked":0}
    ]
```

I want to query on this field of array, and want the output that Number of booked is 1 and not booked are 7.
I have used `JSON_VALUE()`, `JSON_QUERY()` functions but not getting at the point.

I also want that Number:4 is booked.

I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: `I am using SQL Server 2016` ... then why did you tag with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Hi if i understand all what your're trying todo, thoses example can respond :

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[  
       {"number":1,"booked":0},
        {"number":2,"booked":0},
        {"number":3,"booked":0},
        {"number":4,"booked":1},
        {"number":5,"booked":0},
        {"number":6,"booked":0},
        {"number":7,"booked":0},
        {"number":8,"booked":0}
 ]'  

 SELECT number, booked
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
    WITH (number int 'strict $.number', booked int   'strict $.booked')
WHERE booked = 1
```

In futur propose please provide some data and excepted output and query what your're trying .

Answer (score 0):

```
    [
        {"number":1,"booked":0},
        {"number":2,"booked":0},
        {"number":3,"booked":0},
        {"number":4,"booked":1},
        {"number":5,"booked":0},
        {"number":6,"booked":0},
        {"number":7,"booked":0},
        {"number":8,"booked":0}
    ]
```

Select query:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.booked')) 
 OVER(PARTITION BY JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.booked'))
FROM table
GROUP BY JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.booked')
ORDER BY JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.booked')
```