# How can I loop through array of json in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to loop through data to get `taggedEntityName` and `taggedEntityId`:

```
{
    "data": [
              {
                  "taggedEntityName": "Organization",
                  "taggedEntityId": [
                                      145642,
                                      145625
                   ],
                  "index": 0
             },
            {
                 "taggedEntityName": "Job",
                 "taggedEntityId": [
                                      221138
                                   ],
                 "index": 1
             }
           ]
 }
```

Comment: Hi, please provide some sample data and excepted result and current result. Or more explain in what your're trying to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476808/i-need-all-value-from-json-array/55478550#55478550

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you need to use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to parse the input JSON. The structure of the input JSON is always important and in this specific case you need to use `OPENSJON()` with explicit schema twice:

JSON:

```
DEClARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "data": [
              {
                  "taggedEntityName": "Organization",
                  "taggedEntityId": [
                                      145642,
                                      145625
                   ],
                  "index": 0
             },
            {
                 "taggedEntityName": "Job",
                 "taggedEntityId": [
                                      221138
                                   ],
                 "index": 1
             }
           ]
 }'
```

Statement:

```
 SELECT j1.taggedEntityName, j2.taggedEntityId
 FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data') WITH (
    taggedEntityName varchar(50) '$.taggedEntityName',
    taggedEntityId nvarchar(max) '$.taggedEntityId'  AS JSON
 ) j1
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.taggedEntityId) WITH (
    taggedEntityId int '$'
 ) j2
```

Result:

```
taggedEntityName  taggedEntityId
Organization      145642
Organization      145625
Job               221138
```

Comment: I think I will go through this solution.. this is what I was looking for.. :) Once again Thank you so much

Comment: @susmitarai Glad to help!